# try-finally block clarification

Tags: java, try-catch-finally, try-finally

When I try to execute the following function in Java:

```
public static int myfunc (int x) {
    try {
        return x;
    } finally {
        x++;
    }       
}
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int y=5,z;
    z = myfunc(y);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

The output printed on the console is 5, where as one would expect 6 to be printed. Any idea why?

Comment: `return` will supersede any other changes.  Besides, any changes you make to `x` won't be seen outside of the method anyway.  You many also want to investigate the differences between post and pre increments

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Post/pre wouldn't make any difference to the code above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not in the code above, but if the OP tried to do something like `return x++;` in the `finally` block, then it would ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes, but if we're imagining *different* code from what's in the question, any number of things are applicable.

Comment: If you print `y` it will be 6. ;P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is true, but an understand of the concept wouldn't hurt while we're fixing other things ;)

Comment: return: returns control immediately to the caller of its method.  And finally: will always be executed. but will wait for its turn :-)

Answer (score 6):

> ...would expect 6 to be printed. Any idea why?

The `x++` happens *after* the value `5` has been read from `x`. Remember that what follows the `return` statement is an *expression*. When the `return` statement is reached, that expression is *evaluated* (its value is determined), and then that resulting value is used as the function's return value. So in `myfunc`, here's the order of what happens:

1. Enter the `try` block.
2. Evaluate the expression `x` (e.g., get the value of `x`).
3. Set that value as the function's return value.
4. Enter the `finally` block.
5. Increment `x`.
6. Exit the function using the return value from Step 3.

So as of when we leave the function, even though `x` is `6`, the return value was determined *earlier*. Incrementing `x` doesn't change that.

Your code in `myfunc` is analogous to this:

```
int y = x;
x++;
```

There, we *read* the value of `x` (just like `return x` does), assign it to `y`, and then increment `x`. `y` is unaffected by that increment. The same is true for the return value of the function.

It might be clearer with functions: Assuming a `foo` function that outputs `"foo"` and returns 5, and a `bar` function that outputs `"bar"`, then this code:

```
int test() {
    try {
        return foo();
    }
    finally {
        bar();
    }
}
```

...executes `foo`, outputting `"foo"`, then executes `bar`, outputting `"bar"`, and exits from `test` with the return value `5`. You don't expect the function to wait to call `foo` until *after* the `finally` occurs (that would be strange), and indeed it doesn't: It calls it when it reaches the `return foo();` statement, because it evaluates the expression `foo()`. The same is true of `return x;`: It evaluates the expression and remembers the result as of that statement.

Answer (score 4):

Finally block always executes but you returned the value in `try` block itself. After the value of `x` returned, `x` got incremented in `finally`.

```
public static int myfunc (int x) {
    try {
        return x;  // returning
    } finally {
        x++;   // now incremented.
    }       
}
```

*Note:* Just for testing, if you playing with `try-catch-finally`, just return in finally (not recommended) and see.

Answer (score 0):

Finally is executed no matter what, In this case the value is `5` which returned and then incrementing `x`.

```
package qwerty7;

public class Stack {
    public static int myfunc (int x) {
        try {
            return x;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("I'm executing!");
            x++;
        }       
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int y=5,z;
        z = myfunc(y);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}

Output:
I'm executing!
5
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just an addition and a lame version of others' answer**

Let us consider this example below :

```
public class ok {

public static int foo1(int x) {
    try {
        x++;
        System.out.println("foo1 : Inside try before returning I am " + x);
        return x;
    } finally {
        x++;
        System.out.println("foo1 : Inside Finally after post Increment I am " + x);
    }
}

public static int foo2(int x) {
    try {
        x++;
        System.out.println("foo2 : I am inside another method, incremented and changed to " + x);
        return x;
    } finally {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ok o = new ok();
    int val = 10; // The father of all

    int z = foo1(val);
    System.out.println("After executing foo1 I am " + z);

    int x = foo2(val);
    System.out.println("After executing foo2 I am " + x);

    System.out.println("Inside main() and un-altered I am : " + val);
}
}
```

This is just a sample program for better understandability and synchronization of `return`, `try`, `finally`. Whereas, you also must consider the facts, very distinctively provided by :

- **MadProgrammer** : *return will supersede any other changes.*
- **RishiKesh Pathak** : *return: returns control immediately to the caller of its method. And finally: will always be executed. but will wait for its turn*

Thanks, Hope it helps.

*P.S :- Parallely you must also consider accepting an answer here if you feel any of them have closely helped or completely solved your query*

Comment: `return` doesn't 'supercede' anything.The relevant fact is that the *return-expresssion* is already evaluated before the `finally`block executes.

Comment: I have just mentioned another person's comment to explain that even if there is a `finally` the `return` will execute and perform its duty first@EJP. In other words `JUST WHAT YOU HAVE TOLD`, may be `supercede` isn't the closest and perfect word

Comment: @EJP : Have I gone wrong anywhere other than the `supercede` word?   Please rectify me, I would be happy to do so,

Comment: Your new attempt 'the `return` will execute and perform its duty first' is no better. It is simply untrue. What happens first is the *evaluation* of the *return-expression*, as I have already stated. Then the `finally` block. Then the `return`. That should be quite enough 'rectification' for anybody. And we don't need to be SHOUTED AT IN CAPITALS here. People are trying to sleep.

Comment: I was not aware of "the **`evaluation`** of the return-expression", thanks for that but as it says it stands the same that **the `return` is executed first from the program stack while compiling**. Is not it the same regardless the `expression` and the `execution` thing?

Comment: If you think my capital letters have given an impression of `SHOUTING`, then I apologize for that. But my sole intention was to emphasize that `both are same` with respect to output. As far as `people are trying to sleep` is concerned, i personally think that *people are here to help this world rise and awake with possibilities of technology*. But Sorry if that previous comment has offended you. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Value of `x` has returned from `myfunc()` before increment in `finally` block.